# Coded UI doesnot find Control in .Net 4.0 64bit application properly

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, 64-bit, coded-ui-tests

Coded UI Editor is able to find a control in `.Net 3.5 AnyCPU` application

But this application was moved to `.Net 4.0` and Targeted to `64 bit Platform`.

Now the application find the control for the first time and when we press the refresh button the editor (`Coded UI Test Builder Popup`) says

```
Unable to locate the selected UI control
```

Error in the TestLog

```
W, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.140, 19627190016, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, Playback - [WARNING] Internal warning:Search failure: <[UIA]ControlType='TabList' && AutomationId='ADCTRL_TabControl'> | Performed (4) search retries, UI element not found 
V, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.141, 19627190318, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, Playback - 3.5.2013 @15:58:51 
E, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.141, 19627190475, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, Playback - {1} [FAILED] Function ElementFetcher::FindScreenElement failed to locate UI element (Searching: ;[UIA]ControlType='TabList' && AutomationId='ADCTRL_TabControl';[UIA]ControlType='TabPage' && AutomationId='TABITEM_GameSettings';[UIA]ControlType='Button' && AutomationId='SelectableText') (The object specified was not found.) 
E, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.281, 19627573969, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, Playback - [IMAGE] C:\Users\AD\AppData\Local\Temp\UITestLogs\CodedUITestBuilder\LastRun\RPFCBBB.png 
W, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.281, 19627574279, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, Playback - [WARNING] Internal warning: Couldn't find descendants that match QueryId 
W, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.282, 19627575169, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, PERF WARNING: FindAllDescendents: took 4909 ms. Expected it to take maximum 500 ms.
V, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.293, 19627604746, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, AL: Setting search timeout to 120000 ms
V, 6404, 5, 2013/03/05, 15:58:51.293, 19627604912, CodedUITestBuilder.exe, PERF: AL : SearchHelper.Search: took 5067 ms.
```

I am totally confused. I was woring in .NET 3.5 but not .Net 4.0....
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF Coded UI Can't find the control try to send focus before performing actions with the control.
this code works for me.

// seting focus to the UINOButton before using UINOButton control
this.UIWindow2.UINOWindow.UINOButton.SetFocus();